# OnsenUI ons-pull-hook not working in IE11 on WP8.1

Tags: windows-phone-8.1, internet-explorer-11, onsen-ui

I've been trying to make ons-pull-hook work with PhoneGap/Cordova on my WP8.1 device but haven't had much luck with it.

I'm using the official example that can be found here:

```js
ons.bootstrap()
      .controller('DemoController', function($scope, $timeout, $http) {
        $scope.items = [];
        $scope.load = function($done) {
          $timeout(function() {
            $http.jsonp('http://numbersapi.com/random/year?callback=JSON_CALLBACK')
              .success(function(data) {
                $scope.items.unshift({
                  desc: data,
                  rand: Math.random()
                });
              })
              .error(function() {
                $scope.items.unshift({
                  desc: 'No data',
                  rand: Math.random()
                });
              })
              .finally(function() {
                $done();
              });
          }, 1000);
        };
        $scope.reset = function(){
          $scope.items.length = 0;
        }
      });
```

```css
.left {
 text-align: left;
}

img{
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

ons-list-item {
    line-height: 22px !important;
}

.info{
 margin-top: 20px;
 text-align: center;
 opacity: 0.75;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.4/build/css/onsen-css-components.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.4/build/css/onsenui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.4/build/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.4/build/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>

<ons-page ng-controller="DemoController">
      <ons-pull-hook ng-action="load($done)" var="loader">
        <span ng-switch="loader.getCurrentState()">
          <span ng-switch-when="initial"><ons-icon size="35px" icon="ion-arrow-down-a"></ons-icon> Pull down to refresh</span>
          <span ng-switch-when="preaction"><ons-icon size="35px" icon="ion-arrow-up-a"></ons-icon> Release to refresh</span>
          <span ng-switch-when="action"><ons-icon size="35px" spin="true" icon="ion-load-d"></ons-icon> Loading data...</span>
        </span>
      </ons-pull-hook>

      <ons-toolbar>
        <div class="center">Pull to refresh</div>
        <div class="right">
          <ons-toolbar-button ng-click="reset()">Reset</ons-toolbar-button>
        </div>
      </ons-toolbar>

      <ons-list>  
        <ons-list-item ng-show="items.length === 0">
          <div class="info">
            Pull down to fetch items
          </div>
        </ons-list-item>
        <ons-list-item class="item" ng-repeat="item in items">
            <ons-row>
                <ons-col width="80px">
                  <img ng-src="http://lorempixel.com/60/60/?{{item.rand}}" class="item-thum"></img>
                </ons-col>
                <ons-col>
                    <p class="item-desc">{{ item.desc }}</p>
                </ons-col>
            </ons-row>
        </ons-list-item>
      </ons-list>  
    </ons-page>
```

Or in CodePen where the actual http request works http://codepen.io/onsen/pen/WbJogM/ *(don't know why it doesn't here in SO)*

It works just fine on the browser and even using the Ripple emulator on Chrome, but when using Cordova to build and Visual Studio to Deploy to my device, the pull to refresh action does not work at all.

Everything else works just fine, clicks, inputs, scrolling, etc. just the pull to refresh doesn't work. Anyone else having this issue and/or found a solution?

I tried changing different styles to the , tried disabling overscrolling as well without success, I've been searching for days by now.

**EDIT 1:**

It doesn't work with IE11/Edge accessing it directly either, so my guess is that this issue has something to do with IE11/Edge in general and not related to Cordova itself or the visual studio deploy.

**EDIT 2:**

It does, however, work on IE11 Desktop on my Surface Pro 3 via touch emulating Windows Phone...so this must be a very specific issue with the real IE11 for Windows Phone 8.1 itself..

**EDIT 3:**

Adding a simplier example, and it doesn't have anything to do with Cordova nor Visual Studio, but rather how IE11 handles pointerEvents (and maybe it's an issue with Onsen itself), maybe...that's what I've been able to dig so far these past 2-3 days.

```js
ons.bootstrap()
.controller('MyController', function($scope, $timeout) {
    $scope.items = [3, 2 ,1];

    $scope.load = function($done) {
      $timeout(function() {
        $scope.items.unshift($scope.items.length + 1);
        $done();
      }, 500);
    };
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.5/build/css/onsen-css-components.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.5/build/css/onsenui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.5/build/js/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/OnsenUI/OnsenUI/1.3.5/build/js/onsenui.min.js"></script>

<ons-page ng-controller="MyController">
  <ons-toolbar>
    <div class="center">Pull to refresh</div>
  </ons-toolbar>
  <ons-pull-hook var="loaded" ng-action="load($done)">
    <span ng-switch="loader.getCurrentState()">
      <span ng-switch-when="initial">Pull down to refresh</span>
      <span ng-switch-when="preaction">Release to refresh</span>
      <span ng-switch-when="action">Loading data. Please wait...</span>
    </span>
  </ons-pull-hook>
  <ons-list>
    <ons-list-item ng-repeat="item in items">
      Item #{{ item }}
    </ons-list-item>
  </ons-list>
</ons-page>
```

Thanks

Comment: Did you download Onsen UI 1.3.4 module from Visual Studio Gallery? The code need to be changed for WP a bit, like including `ng-csp` and Windows shim. Just wondering if you have all of this prepared.

 Also, can you try with a simple example that doesn't use an HTTP request? Just to make sure the problem is not related to domain stuff.

Comment: @FranDios the thing is that this doesn't have anything to do with the app being deployed to the device at all. I think it's an issue with IE11 on WP8.1 actually, after continuing to debug all day I can't make it work on IE alone (accessing the site via a URL, not even the official codepen example).
Regarding the visual studio stuff, I didn't, I downloaded everything manually and even tried 1.3.5 that was released today. There was another example without the HTTP request, I'll look for it and append it to the original question.

Comment: For some reason the behavior in IE11 sometimes is different than in a deployed Cordova app. We just tested again the Pull Hook using the templates you can find in Visual Studio Gallery and it works well as a Cordova app.

Comment: @AgustinSaldias which version of Cordova are you using?

Comment: @AndiPavllo latest one, but still...I can't make it work not even on IE11 directly on the device, without using Cordova nor Visual Studio...just good old IE on my phone :/. I've been able to find that the hammer event doesn't have, for some reason, the event.center.clientX/Y values, so then hammer can't properly use Detection.extendEventData because there's no info available...I don't know why this isn't working to be honest...thanks for the comments though! I won't give up, yet!

Comment: @AgustinSaldias I wrote the example that you posted and it should work fine, I just tried other pull hook examples in my app and they seem working if deployed as Cordova App. Instead, they'll not work on WP browser because the it's behavior seems to be different. I'll investigate.

Comment: I finally figured out what I was doing wrong, at least on the Cordova/Phonegap side. But, if I try to use onsen-ui as a static mobile site, without cordova, it doesn't work on IE11 on my WP8.1 device..so that's a weird one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I feel **very** dumb to post the answer to my own problem, but I managed to make it work inside Cordova, and it was my mistake. The clues I got from the comments made me realize maybe I wasn't exporting/building the project correctly.

I was using the wp8 platform, instead of the (universal) windows platform, that means that the entire project wasn't 100% compatible with IE on WP8.1 because the wp8 platform depends on the WebView...

What I was doing:

**cordova platform add wp8** -> **cordova build wp8** -> **open the .sln file, change the target platform to wp8.1** -> **deploy to device**

What I'm doing now:

**cordova platform add windows** -> **cordova build windows -- --phone** -> **open the .sln file**

Now everything works just fine.

On the other hand, I'm still not able to make it work on IE11 directly, without cordova.js, so I'm guessing this is an issue with Hammer.js and not Onsen-UI, even though it relies on it and this is what confused me. But that's another issue entirely.

Comment: Thanks for answering back! There is more information about this in Onsen UI blog: http://onsen.io/blog/windows-phone-8-1-tutorial/